# Android creating themes and styles

Tags: android, eclipse, themes, styles, styling

I would like to define a theme for my first Android app. I use Eclipse and I follow [this tutorial](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html) but have problems.

Steps:

A. I create the values/styles.xml file with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="default_splashScreen">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

B. I create the values/themes.xml file with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="SplashScreen">@style/default_splashScreen</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Now Eclipse always complains about the item name="SplashScreen" node with the message "No resource found...". I just want SplashScreen to call default_splashScreen style.

What is wrong?
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Is Eclipse only complaining in the text editor or also when you actually try to compile and run the app? Maybe Eclipse doesn't update the project correctly - try one of the following:

- have you set your project to 'Build automatically'?
- tried a manual project refresh? (right click on project / refresh)
- clean the project via Menu > Project  Clean Project...
- finally: restart Eclipse